# Why do I get white images with black vertical stripes?

Tags: canon, sensor, artifacts, data-corruption

Apparently my 3 year old Canon EOS 550D is fed up with my style of photography and decided to explore abstract arts instead. All it shows on the LCD and stores on the SD card is this:

[image]

When I attempt to gather 'Dust Delete Data', it keeps saying 'Could not obtain the data. Try again." When I switch to movie mode, I get Err 70:

> #### Err 70
>
> Shooting is not possible due to an error. 
>   Turn the camera off and on again or re-install the battery.

What is causing this weird pattern? Is there anything I can try to fix or further diagnose the problem?

After turning it on and off again numerous times, the sensor suddenly functions normally again. However, I am still interested in an explanation of the above pattern.

Comment: By "show", you mean these are the pictures it is either taking or storing? Did you try a different media card?

Comment: In liveview, does it look like this on the LCD, too?

Comment: @inkista: Thanks for asking that. When I switched the camera on to check, it suddenly worked again. You rescued my sightseeing tour for tomorrow!

Comment: @jdv: the pattern is on display and on card

Comment: Sounds like a connection to or from the sensor or image processing bus is flaky. Better bring a backup camera...

Comment: More likely an issue with an internal capacitor that needed to be reformed or backup battery or supercapacitor that was discharged. If you use it successfully for a few dozen photos, the issue probably is resolved. You could test if it reappears if you leave batteries out for a few months ;-)

Answer (score -4):

Electronics get smaller and smaller. I am thinking that when it warms up the buss makes the proper connection due to shrink and expansion. The solder leads must have been manufactured cheep. But this is just a guessing game for me. Same thing has been happening with mac book pros when they warm up they are fine. The electronics warms up and it is ok. But just be ready that after a while the break will be or may be permanent. Something in the video signaling is going bad on the logic board or the main board of your camera. All electronic devices have this so called logic board which is just the mother board everything sits on.